# Return promise in RXJS 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So I just upgraded to RXJS 6 but have this little problem.

```
 getProfile(credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('admin/userstatus-auth', {credentials}).pipe(
        map(res => res))
          .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res);
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
    });
  }
```

So here it says the following:

`Argument of type ‘{credentials : any}’ is not assignable to parameter of type ‘{headers?: HttpHeaders }’`…

[image]

If I do "credentials: HttpHeaders", I get the same error

Comment: Your credentials object doesn't have the right type, you should pass it as an header string

Comment: [Please don't post your code or error as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: could you please tell me how?

Comment: what does `credentials` contain?

Comment: did you try `getProfile(credentials:HttpHeaders){...}` ?

Comment: It's an object containing username and password.

Comment: I did @SurajRao but it doesn't work

Comment: @SaraMesa we need to see credentials object

Comment: why not just `this.http.get('admin/userstatus-auth', ...).toPromise()`? The whole function looks so much wrong

Comment: The error has no relation to your rxjs upgrade, or even rxjs. The 2nd argument that you pass to get doesn't match the expected argument type. See https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this.**

```
 getProfile(credentials) {

    const params = new HttpParams().set('credentials', credentials);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('admin/userstatus-auth', { params: params }).pipe(
        map(res => res))
          .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res);
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
    });
}
```

Comment: @Sara Mesa  if it works for you please mark the answer as correct answer.

Comment: Please give the reason for down voting answer